# How to solve the ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] the target machine actively refused it? (Django SMTP)

Tags: python, django, smtp

I have read many solution tried to implement but no luck.Please suggest to fix this issue and below are the things implemented in my code.

In views.py file

```
    s = smtplib.SMTP(IP Address, Port)
    s.ehlo()
    s.sendmail("a@b.com", 'c@d.com', msg.as_string())
    print("printing the S object", s.__dict__)
    s.quit()
```

Output I am getting:

Connection refused error. win [16001]

Using windows platform, i don't have admin rights, Firewall is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workarounds you can do for this 
* check whether you have permission to connect to SMTP server.You can try netcat or telnet.
* If you are unable to connect to SMTP you have to make sure your local ip should be enabled.

Try with this options which can help you connect SMTP.